# Android listView adaptor error

Tags: android, listview

I define this String Array:

```
String[] mCountryList = new String[200];
```

and fill up the variable with JSON data, and when I use that variable with an `ArrayAdapter`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCountryList);
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I think the String array `mCountryList` can have null values. For example:

```
mCountryList[0]="x";
mCountryList[1]="x";
mCountryList[2]=null;
```

How can I solve this?

The stacktrace I get is:

> 2459-2459/com.example.behzad.behmytour E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>      Process: com.example.behzad.behmytour, PID: 2459
>      java.lang.NullPointerException
>              at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
>              at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
>              at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
>              at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
>              at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
>              at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
>              at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
>              at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
>              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)

Comment: can you post the whole error trace?

Comment: @nr4bt  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Show the whole stacktrace, please please, pretty please. Don't make it difficult for us.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi we cannot even know where is the line you are getting the error. Extend your question by adding `expanded stacktrace` and showing the line you are getting the error

Comment: also you have code mentioning `mCountryList`, then further down it's `mCountr`, what is it now? And "null" is a String, that won't give you an NPE.

Comment: @ci_ i update the my querstion,thanks for pay attention to my problem.

Comment: @behzad, I believe you crashed when the Listview is populated, see ArrayAdapter.getView line in your stacktrace. Please post the code where you populate the Listview. Besides that, I'll post an answer only because I am guessing on the error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of your items is `null`, like you probably thought, but didn't express easily understandable in your question. The solution is, make sure it's not.

[NullPointerException at android widget ArrayAdapter createViewFromResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170322/nullpointerexception-at-android-widget-arrayadapter-createviewfromresource)

You might want to use a `List` instead of an array, and then only populate as many items as you have instead of having a static array with 200 items, unless of course you will always have 200 items.

So use:

```
List<String> mCountryList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

instead of

```
String[] mCountryList=new String[200];
```

and then to populate it, something like this:

```
mCountryList.add("Your String");
```

Comment: Thanks,but how can i set my string array to my adaptor?i'm beginner android

Comment: Using an ArrayList is a good idea, better than using String[], an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is in code `mCountryList[2]=null;`  Even though this is allowed, it is not a good idea to initialize a string to null, certainly not common in Java. Only objects can be set to null.

**Suggestion**: `mCountryList[2]= "";`  Set to a blank string instead.